# Error deploying the DNS Add-on

Tags: kubernetes, coreos

I followed the steps at https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/1.6.1/getting-started.html to install Kubernetes on CoreOS machines.

When I get the pods, looks like everything is working fine.

./kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system

```
NAME                                     READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
calico-node-12g51                        2/2       Running             4          1h
calico-node-dtzss                        2/2       Running             6          1h
calico-node-p35sl                        2/2       Running             4          1h
calico-policy-controller-kh7lz           1/1       Running             2          1h
kube-apiserver-10.201.101.234            1/1       Running             3          2h
kube-controller-manager-10.201.101.234   1/1       Running             3          2h
kube-proxy-10.201.101.234                1/1       Running             3          2h
kube-proxy-10.201.101.236                1/1       Running             7          2d
kube-proxy-10.201.101.237                1/1       Running             5          1d
kube-scheduler-10.201.101.234            1/1       Running             3          2h
```

Then, I follow the steps at https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/1.6.1/deploy-addons.html to deploy DNS add-on.

After that step, I see the kube-dns pod stays at ContainerCreating status forever.

```
kube-dns-v20-htqvx    0/3       ContainerCreating   0          16m
```

./kubectl describe pod kube-dns-v20-htqvx  --namespace=kube-system gives the below log.

```
 FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                    SubObjectPath   Type            Reason          Message
  ---------     --------        -----   ----                    -------------   --------        ------          -------
  16m           16m             1       default-scheduler                       Normal          Scheduled       Successfully assigned kube-dns-v20-htqvx to 10.201.101.237
  15m           15m             1       kubelet, 10.201.101.237                 Warning         FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "CreatePodSandbox" for "kube-dns-v20-htqvx_kube-system(e3f84b85-990d-11e7-9392-005056a16f20)" with CreatePodSandboxError: "CreatePodSandbox for pod \"kube-dns-v20-htqvx_kube-system(e3f84b85-990d-11e7-9392-005056a16f20)\" failed: rpc error: code = 2 desc = NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod \"kube-dns-v20-htqvx_kube-system\" network: Get https://10.3.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-dns-v20-htqvx: dial tcp 10.3.0.1:443: i/o timeout"
```

I see the dial tcp 10.3.0.1:443: i/o timeout error

I assume something is wrong at my installation. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

I seen this kind of issue, when I didn't configure CNI properly. Your using the older version of kubernetes. I would recommend to use the latest version.

your will have better result with this step.

https://cwienczek.com/multi-node-kubernetes-cluster-on-vagrant-in-five-minutes/

Comment: Unfortunately v1.6.1 is marked as the latest on CoreOS + Kubernetes Step By Step guide/page. Do you know the last possible version which I can follow the same steps?

Comment: Do you know where and how to start debugging CNI configuration? I followed the steps at https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/1.6.1/getting-started.html and configured both flannel and calico.  I am not sure if flannel and Calico are mutually exclusive or not.

Comment: they are using flannel for CNI, run the `ip link` see flannel interface configured and ip address assigned on the OS side.